# Why is my old laser mouse so slow on my new Mac?

Tags: macos, mouse

I've got a Microsoft laser mouse that I've had for maybe 15 years. It has always worked well.

But I've been using a Macbook Pro for a couple years, and although I find the trackpad a bit uncomfortable, my mouse doesn't work well with it, either.

The main problem I see is speed: even with the tracking speed at maximum in System Preferences, the cursor moves slowly.

I'm wondering if this is a software issue or a hardware one. Is OSX just not letting me "turn it up to 11" like I want, or is it that the laser mouse has a resolution, where every inch maps roughly to a number of pixels moved, and my current screen has a lot more pixels than those of years ago?

Do I need to change a setting or change my mouse?

Comment: Do you use a mousepad, or do you mouse directly on a table surface?

Comment: @LPChip table surface, which is wood with visible grain.

Comment: I'd treat yourself to a new mouse, in 15 years the technology has definitely gotten better.

Comment: @NathanLong Try using a mousemat. I bet it will drastically improve your mousing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this article: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question631.htm
I would say that your second suggestion is roughly correct.

There may be software you can download that further "speeds up" the mouse, or you could purchase a new one if the trackpad still isn't cutting it for you.

Answer (score 0):

## It was the mouse

I just got a new laser mouse (the [Evoluent VerticalMouse 4](https://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/verticalmouse-4/)). It has a hardware setting for tracking speed, and at higher settings, it tracks much faster than my old laser mouse.